# How can I erase an internal flash Page (not sector!) in my STM32F405RG while using HAL?

Tags: c, gcc, stm32, hal, usb-mass-storage

I've reached a dead end trying manage the internal flash in the STM32F4 microcontroller. There are many examples but most of them use the SPL API or low-level register operations. I am using the HAL libraries. And I cannot find a function to erase just one page (in `stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c` and `stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.c`).
Suggested functions such as `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef *pEraseInit, uint32_t *SectorError)` or `void FLASH_Erase_Sector(uint32_t Sector, uint8_t VoltageRange)` don't allow you to erase one page only (2048 kByte) but only a whole sector (or sectors).
When I try to use something like:

```
void Internal_Flash_Erase(unsigned int pageAddress) {
while (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY);
if (FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_EOP) {
    FLASH->SR = FLASH_SR_EOP;
}

FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_PER;
FLASH->AR = pageAddress;
FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT;
while (!(FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_EOP));
FLASH->SR = FLASH_SR_EOP;
FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_PER;
```

}

a compiler error occurs because there is no `FLASH->AR` (Adress Register) in HAL.
I found reading the [RM0090 Reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) that now I need to use `FLASH->CR` instead AR and set the bits `FLASH_CR_SNB [3:6]` to choose the sector number.

And now I don't know how to erase only one page. It is necessary for creating a Mass Storage Device in internal flash for the function:
`int8_t STORAGE_Write_FS (uint8_t lun, 
                         uint8_t *buf, 
                         uint32_t blk_addr,
                         uint16_t blk_len)`
 in `usbd_storage_if.c` that translates USB-stack calls to internal flash.

Comment: Minimum erasable size for flashes is a sector....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The smallest part you can erase is a sector.

I quote from the reference manual:

> 3.6.3 Erase
>
> The Flash memory erase operation can be performed at sector level or on the
>   whole Flash> memory (Mass Erase). Mass Erase does not affect the OTP sector
>   or the configuration sector.

This is why the sectors have different sizes. It's important to lay out your software to use the sectors cleverly, considering when you might need to erase flash data.

You'er probably going to need to buffer entire sectors in RAM, in order to implement flash-writing with file system-like granularity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But It's very strange for me because I found some examples where page erasing was used.But how it's possible to write some pages to FLASH from USB-host when you need to erase whole sector at first.

Comment: The real  question is: where did you find out that pages exists? What is a page for you?

Comment: For example following documentation: STM32F4 flash memory consists 512 pages (2 Kbytes each). But it is divided by 12 sectors: '/* Base address of the Flash sectors */
0x08000000 Sector 0, 16 Kbytes
0x08004000 Sector 1, 16 Kbytes
0x08008000 Sector 2, 16 Kbytes
0x0800C000 of Sector 3, 16 Kbytes
0x08010000 Sector 4, 64 Kbytes
0x08020000 Sector 5, 128 Kbytes
0x08040000 Sector 6, 128 Kbytes
0x08060000 Sector 7, 128 Kbytes
0x08080000 Sector 8, 128 Kbytes
0x080A0000 Sector 9, 128 Kbytes
0x080C0000 Sector 10, 128 Kbytes
0x080E0000 Sector 11, 128 Kbytes'

Comment: @VshivtsevDaniil And what's the source for that? It's not RM0090. If you look in RM0090, you'll see that no pages in flash are mentioned, since that's not a concept that exists or matters. You can only erase whole sectors.

Comment: @unwind It was screen-shot from [PM0075 Programming manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/10/98/e8/d4/2b/51/4b/f5/CD00283419.pdf/files/CD00283419.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00283419.pdf). And I've got my mistake...

Answer (score 2):

Usually:
copy a flash sector in a table, modify the page in the table, erase the sector, copy the table to the flash sector

Comment: Is this table located in RAM, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I've found my mistake. Examples I found are applied for STM32F103xx. And STM32F103xx flash-memory is really divided into pages (1 or 2 Kbytes). It is possible to erase "sector" that is equal to erase "page". But there are differences in the case of STM32F4xx where flash-memory is divided into sectors.